# Firebase Cloud Firestore ArrayList

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm studying Cloud Firestore. I know it can also save a list type. Let's assume that we have data from index 0 to index 3. Is it impossible to write another value directly to index 4? Existing data values remain unchanged.

Do I have to perform a full reset every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this -- you have to overwrite the entire array. (Or use a dictionary instead)

Arrays tend to be problematic in an environment like Cloud Firestore where many clients could theoretically append or remove elements from an array at the same time -- if instructions arrive in a slightly different order, you could end up with out-of-bounds errors, corrupted data, or just a really bad time.